# basic structure question code not working

Tags: c

I don't understand what is wrong with this code, a very basic doubt. Plz help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct student{
    char name[20];
    int marks;
}student;
int main(){
    student s1;
    scanf("%s\n",s1->name);
    scanf("%d",&s1->marks);
    printf("%s",s1->name[0]);
    printf("%d",s1->marks);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s1->name` ==> `s1.name` .  The `s1` instance isn't a pointer; it's a concrete instance. Member access is with `.` , not `->` . And fyi, even after fixing that in the *four* places its wrong, this:`printf("%s",s1->name[0])` is nonsense. `%s` expects a pointer to char, not a single char. That should read: `printf("%s",s1->name);`

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with structure object initialization

solution

```
typedef struct student{
    char name[20];
    int marks;
}student;
int main(){

    student *s1 = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));

    //check is not null
    if(s1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory failed!.. \n");
    }

    printf("enter your name \n");

    //now read the user input as name
    scanf("%s", s1->name);

    printf("user input %s \n", s1->name);

      //now read the user input as name

    printf("enter your mask \n");

    scanf("%d", &s1->marks);

    printf("the mask %d \n", s1->marks);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why even bother checking if malloc returns null if the OP is using scanf("%s") with no length specifier?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` not `->`. The `->` operator is for pointers.

There are a few other things to mention as well.

When reading strings with `scanf("%s")`, you should always provide the maximum length (which is 20-1=19 in this case) that should be read, otherwise you can get buffer overflow (`scanf` would write past the end of the array).

Also, please note that `scanf("%s")` only reads one word (it finishes when it finds whitespace). Therefore, you shouldn't tell `scanf` to read a `\n`, because if it doesn't find one after the string, it will be bad. The `\n` was probably meant for the call to `printf` instead.

When writing strings, you don't pass `name[0]`, but just `name`. You pass `name[0]` only when printing characters, with `%c`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct student{
    char name[20];
    int marks;
}student;
int main(){
    student s1;
    scanf("%19s", s1.name);
    scanf("%d", &s1.marks);
    printf("%s\n", s1.name);
    printf("%d", s1.marks);
}
```